# Authenticate in Google API with a pop-up in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube

As the title says, i am looking for an efficient and quick way to authenticate in Google API with a pop-up. I don't want anything other than that, since i feel that if the user experiences too much trouble with authenticating, they'll just leave. I don't want to host my own project, since my app is open source, so i cant just put any keys there.

Comment: What type of C# application is this?

Comment: I'm just making a Windows Forms app that would communicate with google/youtube API to send notifications.